# How to get trix-rails work on rails5.2 with a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, trix

iam wondering how i am supposed to implement the new [trix-rails gem](https://github.com/kylefox/trix) in my form.

```
<%=form_for @post do |form| %>
    <p>
      <%= form.label :title %><br/>
      <%= form.text_field :title %>
    </p>

    <p> 
      <%= form.label :content %><br/>

      <%= form.text_area :content %>

    </p>
    <div class="field">
      <%= form.label :image %>
      <%= form.file_field :image %>
    </div>
    <p>
      <%= form.submit "save" %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
<%= form.trix_editor :content %>
```

or something like that isn´t really working ... can someone help me out and tell me how i have to implement it correctly? Thank you so much!

Comment: it should go inside the form...in place of `<%= form.text_area :content %>`

Comment: yeah but when i try to do  

        <p>
          <%= form.label :content %><br/>

          <%= form.trix_editor :content %>
the content field isnt rendered properly, i cant click in it and the editor didnt show up

Comment: maybe css or/and js for trix is missing?

Comment: Yeah thought about that aswell, but I required/imported it like it’s in the readme mentioned. Here is my code on GitHub https://github.com/WebSepp/Blogapp

Answer (score 1):

In your [`application.js`](https://github.com/WebSepp/Blogapp/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/application.js) from GitHub I'm seeing the ordering like this

```
//= require trix
//= require jquery
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

But it would be like this because `trix` is dependable with jquery, so you can use jquery above the list

```
//= require jquery
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require trix
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

and

```
<%= form.trix_editor :content %>
```

put inside the form.

apply like this, I think it will work.

Comment: Thank you very much I will try that! What do you mean with in the form ? I don’t have an extra _form file right now and thought it would be enough to to a form in the new file, wasn’t that correct?

Comment: The `<%= form.text_area :content %>` change to `<%= form.trix_editor :content %>` & remove the below one @Sebastian

Comment: thanks, tried that again but it is still not working, updated my github aswell

Comment: Restart the server & see what happen

Comment: Yeah, also done that. I got 2 deprecation warnings. One for my sprockets method register-engine and one for my processor interface Less::Rails::ImportProcessor ... could that be the mistake?